# Status change to open after receiving email

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have a question and want to know if we can achieve this by SharePoint & flow.
The scenario is, I have created a simple SharePoint list with a choice column (In-Progress and Completed). When I change the status to completed, the users will receive an email that your request has been completed. I was wondering, is there a way if the user replies to the email and status changes to in-progress again?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use the send email action, there is no such way to accept the reply.

As a workaround, use the **send email with options** action as shown below:

[image]

Email recipient needs to reply the email to accomplish the flow, if they need further changes, the related list column will be updated to "In-Progress".

[image]

**----------------------------------Update--------------------------------**

Create a new YES/NO column named "ModifiedByFlow", then click settings of the trigger:

[image]

Then use the expression `@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/ModifiedByFlow'], false)` to add a trigger condition:
[image]

Later, remember to set it as Yes when you update item in flow:

[image]

In this way, if the "ModifiedByFlow" is Yes, the flow trigger will not work.

Comment: Hi Julie, this is a great option. However, I need the email to be sent out when the status changes to Completed. The issue I have now is that I have another field called comments that can be updated at any time, even after the status is completed. So the trigger is when an item or a file is modified. In this case, when they update the comments filed, the WF will trigger again. What's your thought on this? How can we fix this?

Comment: Please check the updated reply.